# OpenCV Getting the correct HSV values

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I'm trying to apply **inRange** in order to find black stains on a lemon.
For some reason, I can't quite find the correct HSV values (I've tried using GIMP and photoshop with no success)

Similar post for reference which I found (in C++): http://answers.opencv.org/question/72176/detect-red-pimples-on-face-using-opencv/

So far my code is quite short:

```
image = cv2.imread("./data/lemon1big.jpg")

# parse BGR to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = np.array([20,5,5],np.uint8)
upper = np.array([68,70,68],np.uint8)
imageHsv = cv2.inRange(imageHsv, lower, upper)

imageAdaptive = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imageHsv,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(1,1))
imageDilate = cv2.dilate(imageAdaptive,kernel)

result, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imageDilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if len(contours) != 0:    
    for (i, c) in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if (area > 700 and area < 1000):
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)            
            cv2.rectangle(result,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),12)
```

Here's the original masked photo:

[image]

The result I look for looks like that (approximately 12 black stains):

[image]

my result looks like so:
[image]

Comment: And how does your result look?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've edited my post with a result (you can ignore the fact I've used circles on top of the original image)

Comment: you dont convert your image to hsv color space, do you?

Comment: @Micka The code in the post didn't include it. Sorry, My bad. I do convert the image from BGR to HSV.

Comment: Is HSV mandatory ? One thing you can try is to process La*b* image and make a grayscale image as Ig = (a* + b*)/2. If the luminosity give you an issue you can normalize by the luminosity Ig = (a* + b*)/(2 x L).

Comment: @Jhon_Sharp1318 No, it is not. Can you express your answer in code? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Lab = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    L,a,b = cv2.split(Lab.astype(np.float32))
     
    # solution 1) the lightness is not an issue
    Ig1 = cv2.addWeighted(a,0.5,b,0.5,0)
    Ig1 = cv2.normalize(Ig1,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)
    
    # solution 2) the lightness is an issue
    Ig2 = cv2.addWeighted(a/L,0.5,b/L,0.5,0)
    Ig2 = cv2.normalize(Ig2,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)

Comment: @Jhon_Sharp1318 i can't differentiate the black stains with any of your examples :( What could I do wrong?